# Eclipse doesn't read the StdDraw jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to draw a triangle in eclipse:

```
public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double t = Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0;
        StdDraw.line(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        StdDraw.line(1.0, 0.0, 0.5, t);
        StdDraw.line(0.5, t, 0.0, 0.0);
        StdDraw.point(0.5, t/3.0);
    }
}
```

And it shows in the result that:

```
StdDraw cannot be resolved.
```

I have already created the JAR file from StdDraw.java (http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw.java.html)
and I have also added it to the Java Build Path.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.